# Manipulating a version of summations to produce the closed formula for the Catalan Numbers.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, catalan-numbers

Manipulate $g(x) = \frac{1}{2x}\left(1 - \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{1/2 \choose k}(-4x)^k\right)$ into $g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{1/2 \choose n+1}(-1)^n2^{2n+1}x^n$

I know that I should substitute n + 1 for k to allow the summation to begin at 0, so I can see where part of the second representation comes from, but am lost on how to manipulate the other parts to obtain the desired form. Can anyone explain how to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
\frac1{2x}\left(1-\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom{1/2}k(-4x)^k\right)&=\frac1{2x}\left(1-\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom{1/2}k(-1)^k2^{2k}x^k\right)\\
&=\frac1{2x}\left(1-\sum_{k\ge -1}\binom{1/2}{k+1}(-1)^{k+1}2^{2k+2}x^{k+1}\right)\\
&=\frac1{2x}-\sum_{k\ge -1}\binom{1/2}{k+1}(-1)^{k+1}2^{2k+1}x^k\\
&=\frac1{2x}+\sum_{k\ge -1}\binom{1/2}{k+1}(-1)^k2^{2k+1}x^k\\
&=\frac1{2x}+\binom{1/2}0(-1)^{-1}2^{-1}x^{-1}+\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom{1/2}{k+1}(-1)^k2^{2k+1}x^k\\
&=\frac1{2x}-\frac1{2x}+\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom{1/2}{k+1}(-1)^k2^{2k+1}x^k\\
&=\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom{1/2}{k+1}(-1)^k2^{2k+1}x^k
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thanks, do you have any suggestions on documentation for working with binomial coefficients? I'm now trying to manipulate 1/2 choose n+1 and 2n choose n into alternate forms.

Comment: @mandib: You're welcome. It really depends on what sorts of forms you're aiming for. You do have $$\binom{1/2}{k+1}=\frac{(-1)^k(2k-1)!!}{2^{k+1}(k+1)!}=\frac{(-1)^k(2k)!}{2^{2k+1}k!(k+1)!}=\frac{(-1)^k}{2^{2k+1}(k+1)}\binom{2k}k\;,$$ if I haven't loused up doing the algebra in my head and typing on a small mobile device, and that last is $$\frac{(-1)^k}{2^{2k+1}}C_k\;.$$

Comment: For $$\binom{1/2}{k+1}$$, I'm trying to force it into $$\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{n-1/2}{n}(-1)^n\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: If I were able to just produce a proof for the Catalan numbers I would have this in the bag, but manipulating these into specific forms is killing me figuratively.

Comment: @mandib: Notice that if you combine the final summation in my answer with the result in the previous comment, you get $g(x)=\sum_{k\ge 0}C_kx^k$, which I suspect is what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

> A slightly different variation:
>
> \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{2x}\left(1-\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{\frac{1}{2}}{k}(-4x)^k\right)&=
> \frac{1}{2x}\left(-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\binom{\frac{1}{2}}{k}(-4x)^k\right)\tag{1}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2x}\left(-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\binom{\frac{1}{2}}{k}(-1)^k2^{2k}x^k\right)\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\binom{\frac{1}{2}}{k}(-1)^{k-1}2^{2k-1}x^{k-1}\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{\frac{1}{2}}{k+1}(-1)^{k}2^{2k+1}x^{k}\tag{4}\\
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) the summand with $k=0$ cancels out
- In (2) we write $(-4x)^k=(-1)^k2^{2k}x^k$
- In (3) we multiply each summand of the series with $-\frac{1}{2x}$
- In (4) we shift the index $k$ by one to start from zero